# Generate terraform import commands from a terraform state file

Tags: terraform, terraform-cloud, terraform-state

I have a bit of a dummy question. First of all a bit of context:

I am using terraform cloud and have two workspaces called `mydata_old` and `mydata_new`. My goal is to do a partial workspace migration from `mydata_old` to `mydata_new` meaning that I want some of the configuration to now only exist to mydata_new and get removed from `mydata_old`. Is there any way just by looking at a state file example [here](https://github.com/mdb/terraform-example/blob/master/terraform/terraform.tfstate) to know exactly which import commands you have to execute?

Comment: I think it would be better to look at the terraform code and see from there what you want to import.

Comment: I dont have access to the code form the previous workspace, just the state file @MarkoE

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the old state is not complete information to know exactly which import command to execute... but it can help you build it, you need to know the Terraform resources in the new workspace.

Let's use as an example that state file example you provided:
https://github.com/mdb/terraform-example/blob/master/terraform/terraform.tfstate

One of the resources there is:

```txt
...
                "aws_s3_bucket_object.css_file": {
                    "type": "aws_s3_bucket_object",
                    "depends_on": [
                        "aws_s3_bucket.site"
                    ],
                    "primary": {
                        "id": "assets/stylesheets/application.css",
                        "attributes": {
                            "bucket": "mikeball.me",
                            "cache_control": "",
                            "content_disposition": "",
                            "content_encoding": "",
                            "content_language": "",
                            "content_type": "text/css",
                            "etag": "cbb4dfe4ff59c374f4d131f6f043e27e",
                            "id": "assets/stylesheets/application.css",
                            "key": "assets/stylesheets/application.css",
                            "kms_key_id": "",
                            "source": "../dist/assets/stylesheets/application.css",
                            "version_id": ""
                        }
                    }
                },
...
```

and let's assume your new terraform code for that resource is something like:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "css" {
  bucket = "your_bucket_name"
  key    = "assets/stylesheets/application.css"
  source = "../dist/assets/stylesheets/application.css"
  etag = filemd5("../dist/assets/stylesheets/application.css")
}
```

According to the documentation we can import using the S3 url...
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_object#import

here is how that import command will look like

```
terraform import aws_s3_bucket_object.css s3://your_bucket_name/assets/stylesheets/application.css
```